# How can I store the values of nodes of a binary search tree in a string?

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am trying to store all values of the nodes in a binary search tree in ascending order in a string. I managed to print them out but storing them in a string seems a little more complicated Any ideas?

This is how i print them out:

```
public void inOrder() {
    if (this.left != null) {
        this.left.inOrder();
    }
    System.out.print(this.value + " ");
    if (this.right != null) {
        this.right.inOrder();
    }
}
```

I am looking for this method:

```
public String inOrder() {
    // ???
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since there is no entire code example here, I will post it myself. However, I wonder why there is not a single example on the internet. So here we go. I assume that the binary search tree uses integers for the values of its nodes:

```
public String inOrder() {
    String asc = "";
    if (this.left != null) {
        asc += this.left.inOrder();
    }

    asc = asc + this.value + " ";

    if (this.right != null) {
        asc += this.right.inOrder();
    }
    return asc;
}
```

Please, leave a comment if you found this helpful or if you have a better approach!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling your search function recursively, I'd recommend concating the values to a global string (`mystring` in this case) via

```
mystring.concat(this.value);
```

instead of trying to return the string from the function call itself.